TypeOrm adds extra unique index to each column of a composite unique index
I have this typeorm model with a composite unique index:

@Entity({name: "positions"})
@Unique("constraint_unique_position", ["role_id", "organisation_id", "soato"])
export class Position {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    role_id: number

    @OneToOne(() => Role)
    @JoinColumn({name: "role_id"})
    role: Role;

    @Column()
    organisation_id: number

    @OneToOne(() => Organisation)
    @JoinColumn({name: "organisation_id"})
    organisation: Organisation;

    @Column()
    @MaxLength(7, {message: "soato must be 7 characters maximum"})
    soato: number

    @OneToMany(() => PositionPermissions, (perm:PositionPermissions) => perm.position)
    permissions: PositionPermissions[]
}

As you can see role_id, organisation_id, soato make a composite unique index. But when I inspect the generated table, along with the composite unique index each of these column have their own unique index:

As a result, I can't insert a value twice to a column:
INSERT INTO positions (
    role_id,
    organisation_id,
    soato,
    status
) VALUES (
    5, 2, 17
), (
    4, 2, 17
);

This gives error as value 2 is already inserted to organisation_id.
Is my table wrong?
How can I achieve to only have the composite unique index created?
